# Can one become suddenly ambidextrous?

Tags: neuroscience

Is it possible to become ambidextrous? i'm 67 and recently and suddenly became ambidextrous about a month ago. I can write w both hands at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in a right handed person the left hemisphere is considered dominant.  However, a new lesion in the left hemisphere can cause loss of this dominance so it is possible that this has occurred.

Alternatively, if the subject is now able to write using both hands concurrently but different material, it suggests that the two hemispheres are disconnected, the so called [split brain syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain) which occurs with lesions of the corpus callosum.  However, ambidexterity is not described in that syndrome.

Anyway, you need to consult your physician.

Comment: Nice that someone affirms that this can happen. The brain is a mysterious organ, and I agree that a brain lesion can cause this. It would be interesting to compare quality of writing in each hand.

Answer (score -3):

You can't suddenly become ambidextrous.  You can train yourself to use objects with the opposite hand, and become use to using your other hand.

Your body learns on repetition- Repeating something over and over till it becomes a habit.  It takes time for your body to adjust to the change but you can become ambidextrous through training your body.

You just have to have the patience and the will to do it.

Comment: If this at all helps you.  Show some support.

Comment: Answers at Biology.SE require some references to be complete, especially for anything that goes beyond sort of "general textbook" knowledge.